# eval parse save string to variable

Tags: r, string, eval

I have table with variable names and observation for this variable. Some of these observations should be saved to variable as text.

I can't find any other way to deal with except the following, which is not working:

```
x    <- data.frame( c("Name1","Name2","Name3"),
                    c("Result1",2,"Result3") )
txt  <- paste(x[,1], "<-", x[,2], sep="")
eval(parse(text=txt))
```

Error in eval(parse(text = txt)) : object 'Result1' not found

I need to get the result where Name1 = "Result1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should not be creating such multiple objects in the global environment. It is difficult to manage them. However, for some reason if you have to do it here is one way :

```
data <- type.convert(setNames(as.list(x[[2]]), x[[1]]), as.is = TRUE)
list2env(data, .GlobalEnv)
```

We create a named list where value is from 2nd column and name is from 1st column of `x`. We then use `type.convert` to convert the data into their respective types. Finally use `list2env` to have `Name1`, `Name2`, `Name3` as variables in your global environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. The issue is that objects like `Result1` or `Result2` can not be found:

```
#Data
x    <- data.frame( c("Name1","Name2","Name3"),
                    c("Result1",2,"Result3") )
#Text
txt  <- paste(x[,1], "<-", '\"',x[,2],'\"', sep="")
#Evaluation    
eval(parse(text=txt))
```

If numeric needed to be kept, play with data types:

```
#Data
x    <- data.frame( c("Name1","Name2","Name3"),
                    c("Result1",2,"Result3"),stringsAsFactors = F )
#Text
txt  <- ifelse(!is.na(as.numeric(x[,2])),paste(x[,1], "<-", as.numeric(x[,2]), sep=""),
               paste(x[,1], "<-", '\"',x[,2],'\"', sep=""))
#Eval
eval(parse(text=txt))
```

Comment: Is there any way to keep 2nd variable as numeric?

Comment: @Sam I have added an update, I hope that helps you!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you might need to adapt your data.frame `x` a bit like below

```
x <- data.frame(
  c("Name1", "Name2", "Name3"),
  c("Result1", 2, "Result3")
)
x[,2] <- type.convert(x[,2],as.is = TRUE)
x[,2] <- ifelse(is.na(as.numeric(x[,2])),paste0("\'",x[,2],"\'"),x[,2])
```

where single quotes `''` are needed to wrap `Result1` and `Result2`

Then you will see

```
> Name1
[1] "Result1"

> Name2
[1] 2

> Name3
[1] "Result3"

> class(Name1)
[1] "character"

> class(Name2)
[1] "numeric"

> class(Name3)
[1] "character"
```

Comment: I am importing a long list from csv. Would have to do this with loop I guess?

Comment: @Sam see my update. You need one more line to add the single quotes

Comment: I think 2nd column is facto and this is turning it to levels I think. Now it looks like this: 
1                        Name1                          2
2                        Name2                          2
3                        Name3                          2

Comment: @Sam Then you need `x[,2] <- type.convert(x[,2],as.is = TRUE)`. See the update