# how to create multiple vector once a time in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to do this:

```
a <- 101
b <- 102
c <- 103
d <- 104
e <- 105
```

But I don't want to type it one by one, so I tried this but failed:

```
df <- data.frame(name = letters[1:5],
                 values = 101:105)

assign(x = df$name, value = df$values)
```

Any help will be highly appreciated！

Comment: This is similar : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64078413/eval-parse-save-string-to-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `list2env` to assign a named list of variables to a target environment. If you want to use them as "normal" variables in a script, the environment would be `.GlobalEnv`

```
vars <- as.list(101:105)
names(vars) <- letters[1:5]

list2env(vars,.GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: And if you want to use a dataframe, you can use this along with `mapply`: `list2env(mapply(assign, df$name, df$values, SIMPLIFY = FALSE), envir = globalenv())`